# java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)

Tags: android, alfresco, httpurlconnection, cmis, opencmis

I'm trying to query Alfresco repository through OpenCMIS from Android.
But getting below error but not every time. 
Here is my code. This code working fine when I run as a standalone program but does not working fine with Android.

```
getCMISClientSession();
ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query("SELECT * FROM cmis:document 
                   where cmis:name ='"+docName+"'", false);

for (QueryResult result : results) { //Exception thrown from here

    String docId = result.getPropertyValueById(PropertyIds.OBJECT_ID);
    doc = (Document)session.getObject(docId);

}
```

Stackstrace

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Cannot access http://<192.168.1.122>:8080/alfresco/cmisatom/eee7da3c-d3d4-48de-89a1-52145a6a6e06/query: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.HttpUtils.invoke(HttpUtils.java:224)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.HttpUtils.invokePOST(HttpUtils.java:74)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:561)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.DiscoveryServiceImpl.query(DiscoveryServiceImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl$3.fetchPage(SessionImpl.java:567)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getCurrentPage(AbstractIterator.java:132) 
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.CollectionIterator.hasNext(CollectionIterator.java:48)
```

Is this because Android Emulator is slow? Please advice how can I resolve this error.

Comment: What version (librairies) of OpenCMIS do you use ? the Android client ?

Comment: @JM.Pascal, yes, the Android client

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this version [0.8.0-alfresco-patched](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/service/local/repositories/thirdparty/content/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-android-client/0.8.0-alfresco-patched/chemistry-opencmis-android-client-0.8.0-alfresco-patched.jar) or eventually with the latest one from [Apache chemistry CI](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-android-client/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/)

Answer (score 0):

Emulators don't work for apps which require Internet connection. Try with real device .